# radio group not listening inside of a dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

I can't listen to the RadioGroup from my DialogFragment class. I don't get eny errors, but 
the Log doesn't show me anything. Please help me...

```
public class SimpleDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio, null);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_name)
            .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio, null))
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           });


    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            Log.v("Dialog", "checked");
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Comment: Is the `RadioGroup` basic functionality working, i.e., when you select a Radio, the previously active Radio automatically deselects?

Comment: I just figured it out, I have to pass to builder.setView(view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, I have to pass to builder.setView(view)